# EntityFramework 6 and mongodb and Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mongodb, asp.net-identity-2

I am using WebAPi project and I would like to setup EntityFramework 6 with Mongodb.

I have setup my mongodb database and my entity framework code first model by following this link:

[http://cdn.rssbus.com/help/DG1/ado/pg_efCodeFirst.htm](https://github.com/g0t4/aspnet-identity-mongo)

Now I would like to get Entity Framework and Asp.net Identity 2 to work together based on Mongodb. However, I cannot find any way ormodules that allow to do it. I found the following but it explains to uninstall entity framework.

https://github.com/g0t4/aspnet-identity-mongo

So would you know a tuorial or would you have any experiences to enable mongodb for EF Code first and with IDentity working with?

THanks,

Comment: " Entity Framework and Asp.net Identity 2 to work together based on Mongodb" How do you see this working? what exactly are the requirements?

Comment: Instead of SqlServer database I would like to use Mongodb. But I have some issues. If I use the standard Identity 2 it does not work with Mongodb. If I use aspnet-identity-mongo I cannot use ef code first. So I do not know how I can use EF code first + aspnet-identity-mongo + mongodb

Comment: EF does not work with Mongo, so you can't have it all. Either EF or Mongo. Or have EF for your domain data and users stored in Mongo. Or Domain data stored in Mongo but Identity using SQL Server with EF.

Comment: to add to @trailmax comment, EF6 doesn't work with any non-relational data stores at all. EF7 will support non-relational including nosql. Currently they have a proof of concept API that works with Azure Table Storage. I expect that eventually there will be providers for other  nosql dbs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so I finally found a solution.

I am not using EF anymore.

I am using AspNet Identity Mongo with the V2 branch I compiled.

https://github.com/InspectorIT/MongoDB.AspNet.Identity/tree/v2

I am using MongoRepository for the repository of my Model.

https://github.com/RobThree/MongoRepository

And I have developed a DataService to manage my models CRUD operations.

```
 public class DataService
{
    public static MongoRepository<ModelClass> ModelClass{ get { return Singleton<MongoRepository<ModelClass>>.Instance; } }


}

public class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    Singleton() { }

    private static readonly Lazy<T> instance = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());

    public static T Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }
}
```

And I am good.

Thanks,

Comment: What did u use instead of ef for mapping