# Is it possible to use Entity Framework Core 6 with MongoDb?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, entity-framework-core, nosql

Is it possible to use EF Core 6 in combination with a MongoDb? From what I'v gathered online, I could only find answers from a few years ago that say that it's still not possible, but nothing that was published recently. There is also better support for the Azure Cosmos Db which is also a NoSql database, so maybe I could use that to communicate with a MongoDb?

If it's still not possible, what other approach should I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EntityFramework 6 and mongodb and Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099488/entityframework-6-and-mongodb-and-identity)

Comment: Do you insist to use Entity-Framework? For me it seems to be a dying technology. MongoDB is a schema-less database, that contradicts to idea of object-relational mapping. At least "database-first" approach seems to be impossible.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit what on earth made you say entity framework is a 'dying technology' - i feel like you can't be further from the truth. EF is an ORM - and i doubt ORM's will be anything but dying for the next few years, and EF core is still being actively developed on

Comment: That's just my personal feeling. In SO the [trend](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=entity-framework) goes down. It is not part anymore of the standard .NET. Maybe it is not dying, however 10 years ago it was more "in vogue". Anyway, coming back to the actual question: even in [Plan for Entity Framework Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan) term "NoSQL" is not mentioned, so I guess it is still not possible.

Comment: @Jazb The post is a little bit old, but does confirm what I thought.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It's for a school presentation about EF & MongoDb, so yeah I kind of need it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Your perception is skewed here i believe, EF has gained more popularity. The reason the trend went down is because the tag `entity-framework` is for the old EF, check the upcoming trend for EF core: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=entity-framework%2Centity-framework-core its also not part of standard .net but thats because the whole library is moving into seperate packages (more akin java's framework) - so it definitely is still part of the Fx - and is still a critical part of ASP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>There is no official MongoDb provider implementation for EF core at this time, I did not see any mention of MongoDb in the .net core 7 (the next version) roadmap as of now.</s>

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

I quickly googled a bit but could not find a recent version of a MongoDb provider.

Msdn docs also do not use EF core:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Related SO:
[MongoDB and Entity Framework Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218719/mongodb-and-entity-framework-core-2-0)

**UPDATE**

From the ['supported providers' table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), MongoDb is now supported!

| NuGet Package | Supported database engines | Maintainer / Vendor | Notes / Requirements | For EF Core | Useful links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore/) | MongoDB | MongoDB | Currently in preview | 7 | [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/entity-framework/current/) |

See the [quickstart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/entity-framework/current/quick-start/#std-label-entity-framework-quickstart)!

Comment: This answer is outdated - see [Answer from vlee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75214105/18306894). Since October 12, 2023 there exists a [MongoDB Provider for Entity Framework Core in Public Preview](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-provider-entity-framework-core-now-available-public-preview)

Answer (score 9):

MongoDB has now released an officially supported EF Core provider (currently in preview).

Github repo:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-efcore-provider

NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore

Issue/bug tracker:
https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/EF/issues/EF-63

Answer (score 2):

While there is no MongoDb provider for EF (to my disappointment), there is, at least, a provider for CosmosDb, Azure's fully managed NoSQL solution.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cosmos-db/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Once can't help but wonder if it's intentional -- but I imagine the unit-of-work pattern with transaction rollback as well as Migrations support.

In the mean time, you can consider something along the lines of the repository pattern so that your data access does not depend on your infrastructure.

I'd recommend taking a look at some of the samples and training by [Ardalis](https://ardalis.com) (Steve Smith).

https://deviq.com/design-patterns/repository-pattern

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2023 an offical MongoDB Provider for EF Core is now in Public Preview.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-provider-entity-framework-core-now-available-public-preview

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-efcore-provider

A production worthy version might still be some way off though.