# Is there an ADO.Net connector allowing to read a Realm database?

Tags: c#, mongodb, ado.net, realm

As in the title, do you know if there is an ADO.Net connector allowing to read a Realm database?

For now I m going to try with CData.MongoDB or MongoDB.Driver (nugets packages ) even if I'm almost sure it won't work on my database.realm file - plus, I m afraid it need a server ...

I keep you update, thanks you already :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is a bit vague. Realm is an offline first database and stores its data locally. Are you asking how to connect to that? If Realm is sync'd it also stores it's data on a server - and that back end data is stored as a NoSQL database known as MongoDB. Which are you trying to connect to? MongoDB supports CRUD operation and is REST compliant and there are a variety of SDK's involving Realm. Or are you just trying to get to the server data? Please update and clarify the question.

Comment: The goal is to replace SQLite (currently used) with a Realm database (without synchronizing with a MongoDB server). 

For reading and writing the Realm SDK would be perfect.

On the other hand, another application would need to connect to the Realm database (file) via an ADO.Net connector

 ( -> more in the second comment !  )

Comment: By this I mean that with Ado.Net, each data provider (SQL, SqLite, ODBC, ORACLE,…) has its own classes prefixed by his name ( SqliteConnectionStringBuilder , SqliteConnection, … Odbc for odbc, Oracle for Oracle …)

I would like to find an equivalent for Realm ( or a generic one?) , in order to be able to communicate with Ado.Net towards a Realm database.

Does one exist?

Sorry that my first post was blurry and thank you so much for your response ! 
Next time I will be more careful to specify the context as much as possible :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I Had an answer from a MogoDB employee :
"Unfortunately, we don’t have an ADO.NET client. We do have a .NET SDK that allows you to interface with the database, but it doesn’t provide integration with ADO.NET."
Sadly I absolutely have to go through Ado .Net.
I will therefore study other databases.
Thank you so much ! I close subject :)

Comment: More of a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

See the following links which may be helpful in finding a solution using Entity Framework or Dapr:

- [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70618359/is-it-possible-to-use-entity-framework-core-6-with-mongodb)
- [Dapr](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/adventures-with-dapr-persisting-to-mongo-db-in-net-bd4272c8c7e5)